# Can I model a character in blender, export it to maya, run xgen to create hair, then export it back into blender for animation?

Tags: animation, export, transforms, hair, alembic

Can I model a character in Blender, export it to Maya, run xgen to create hair, then export it back into Blender for animation?

I need an help to understand how can I export xgen hair to Blender and animate them.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)